# Why am I getting junk in VSCode Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason I've started getting junk coming in with my Intellisense. I'm looking for a way to turn off maybe...Global Identifiers? It's like it's somehow started looking through lots and and lots of files to match *anything* I type in.

[image: Junk in VSCode Intellisense]

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Do these go away if you set `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false`? What if you disable all of your installed extensions?